# SQL Join and union All

Tags: sql, mysqli

I am trying to join 3 tables in SQL. 
Table1

```
CustomerID   FirstName   LastName    Address       EmailAddress      
 1             bob               S             1111        xxx@yahoo.com
 2             jim               B             2222        777@yahoo.com
 3             hank              H             333         kkk@yahoo.com
```

Table2

```
 CustomerID     Date    MemberID
   1           5/15/86  1
   2           5/16/86  2
```

Table3

```
 CustomerID     Lengthofstay
   1               5
   2              16
```

As you can see I have 3 customer in Table 1. I need to join all 3 table. But in table 2 and 3 I need it to be NULL where customer 3 doesn't have any info for table 2 and 3. It would still have all of customers 3 info that is table 1 but the blank info that isn't there for customer 3 would be NULL.

I have Tried this but it leaves out customer 3:

```
SELECT      
A.CustomerID,
A.Firstname,
A.Lastname,
A.Address,
A.EmailAddress,
B.CustomerID,
B.Date,
B.memberID,
C.CustomerID,
C.LengthofStay

FROM TABLE1 as A
JOIN Table2 as B on ( A.CustomerID = B.CustomerID)
LEFT JOIN TABLE3 as C on ( A.CustomerId = C.CustomerID)
```

This leaves out customer 3. I have tried using:

`WHERE A.CustomerID IS NULL;` but I get nothing back. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, your nearly there, you need to convert the first join to a LEFT JOIN:

```
SELECT      
A.CustomerID,
A.Firstname,
A.Lastname,
A.Address,
A.EmailAddress,
B.CustomerID,
B.Date,
B.memberID,
C.CustomerID,
C.LengthofStay

FROM TABLE1 as A
LEFT JOIN Table2 as B on ( A.CustomerID = B.CustomerID)
LEFT JOIN TABLE3 as C on ( A.CustomerId = C.CustomerID)
```

Comment: will this provide the NULL value for customer 3 in the table 2 and 3 values? Thanks

Comment: Yes the values returned from TableB & TableC for customer 3 will be null. see http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/237ce4/1/0